# selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g") does not work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For some reason,

```
chart.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g")
```

does not work, but

```
chart.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
```

does work. By "work", I mean the element represented by `chart` finally contains many "`rect`"/"`g`, one for each data item. The second line causes the element to finally contain many `rect`, but nothing will appear if `g` is used. Any ideas why a simple change from `rect` to `g` will cause a bug?

Code:

```
var chart  = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // setup chart axis.
        chart.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .call(xAxis);

          chart.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text(yLabel);

    // Pertinent code here    
    var rows = chart.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g");
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you want, but:

if you want something like:

```
svn 
  g //one g for every data row
  g //y axis
  g //x axis
```

then something like this should work:

```
var chart  = svg
var chartLines = chart
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
 .attr("class", "line");

// setup chart axis.
    chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .call(xAxis);

      chart.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(yLabel);

// Pertinent code here    
var rows = chart.selectAll(".line").data(data).enter().append("g");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are a lot of `g` elements on the page already when you run this code -- some of them added by you, some of them added by D3 when you call the axis component. There are however no `rect` elements, so that code works.

There are several ways around this -- you can either run the code that binds the data to the `g` elements first, add axis and chart in separate `g` elements, add a class to the `g` elements that you're binding the data to, or any combination of these.

Some more background and examples in [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/d3.js/getting-started-tutorial).